# c++ add new row datagridview

Tags: c++, datagridview

I'm using Visual Studio c++ forms. I took default datagridview from a tool box, and changed nothing from options. whenever I run program I get error message 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException', because not creating a new row to a table.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
 datagridview->Rows[i]->Cells[1]->Value = i; }
```

Comment: are you sure that `datagridview` has 3 rows and each has 1 column ?

Comment: The matter of fact it has 1 row 4 column. I don't know how to add row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed add this line of code which create new row:

```
datagridview->Rows->Add();
```